# What does "to be presented with somebody in mind" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can anybody explain it for me, please? I used this link:
[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/presented?s=t)

> Daily Table regularly carries staples like off-brand Cheerios for 63 cents, cans of tuna for 50 cents, and bananas at 29 cents a pound. Rauch, however, says customers can’t expect to get all of their staples at the store. You can’t find oils and spices, for example.
>   Still, all of the options inside the store are informed by nutrition experts, Rauch says. Everything **is presented with children and families in mind**. And all of the products are priced low enough to accommodate recipients of food stamps.
>
> ([Source](http://fortune.com/2017/06/05/food-waste-daily-table/))

Comment: Edited. But in future, please use `[hyperlink](link)` and `> quote clock`. Don't be too sloppy; nice editing would attract answerers.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure what they mean. What's the difference between presenting food with families, and with unmarried people without a family or some such in mind? We all, including children, eat the same food. They even eat spinach (ew). Anyway, what you want to look at is [this](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/with-somebody-something-in-mind) to understand the sentence.

Comment: Thanks, @userr2684291. I think they mean children and families are their top priority so they always try to sell foods with as high quality as they can.